# E3JK-R2R3 wiring

Tags: sensor, wiring, plc

[image]

Hi, this is E3JK-R2R3, brown and blue connect to power supply. I wanted to know is it either black or brown connect to +load and the white connect to 0V?

If is it so, I don't see the electric flow.

Comment: This isn't a complete internal diagram, they only gave you enough to understand how to wire external components.

Comment: You need an external power supply for the load.  The E3JK just switches the low side of the load to the negative terminal of the external supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the foolish error in the picture so maybe you understand it now: -

[image]

If you look in the latest data sheet for the device ([found here](https://sg.rs-online.com/web/p/photoelectric-sensors/7452102/)), this error is fixed: -

[image]

Comment: Either grey or black connect to +24VDC, the white connect to PLC. Am I right?

Comment: Grey or black connect to individual loads (as per above). The other side of the load can connect to 24 volts but, the negative end of the 24 volts must also connect to white. The loads above can be inputs to a PLC provided the inputs are rated to take 24 volts but, in all likelihood, you might need to use a pull-up resistor between grey (and black) and the 24 volt supply. The 24 volt supply can be the same as that supply that connects to brown and blue.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for your help.